# ¿Se puede obtener el nombre de la instancia de una clase?

Tags: java

No se si este bien redactada la pregunta pero esta es la cuestión.

Tengo mi clase `ProductosLacteos`. Cuando yo creo la instancia hago esto:

```
ProductosLacteos quesito = new ProductosLacteos();
```

Entonces yo quiero obtener `quesito` como una cadena de texto. ¿Para que? Cuestión de debugueo. Tengo una consola donde se muestran diferentes datos del programa, pero el plan es que dentro de `ProductosLacteos` pueda acceder a el nombre de la instancia con `getNombreDeLaInstancia()`.  Esto es lo que espero:

```
ProductosLacteos quesito = new ProductosLacteos();
ProductosLacteos lechita = new ProductosLacteos();
ProductosLacteos jocoque = new ProductosLacteos();

System.out.println(quesito.getNombreDeLaInstancia());
System.out.println(lechita.getNombreDeLaInstancia());
System.out.println(jocoque.getNombreDeLaInstancia());
```

Y me de resultado:

> "quesito"
>   "lechita"
>   "jocoque"

¿Será posible acceder a este dato con `extends` de manera que lo tenga disponible para todas mis clases?

Gracias!

Comment: Y con que fin ademas de debugeo? Si al final eres tu mismo que escribes el nombre de la instancia porque no lo escribes directamente en el println

Comment: Facilitarme la vida. Solo eso. De manera que yo no tenga que escribir una linea más por cada print. Tener a la mano toda la información de debugueo y por que me entro la curiosidad. Si

Comment: En mi opinión, conocer el nombre de la variable no ayuda mucho. Ayuda más conocer el método donde apareció el error, la clase a la que pertenece el método, el número de línea exacto, el tipo de problema y demás. Problemas que resuelven muy bien las librerías de logging.

Comment: No intento rastrear errores, si no secuencias. De manera que sea más fácil describir en consola el modelo de negocios que trato de programar. Como dices los errores son fácilmente rastreables con los medios que hay pero los "horrores" de programación no. Tengo una clase que paso como parametro  "Runnable". Esta clase la he instanciado montones de veces. La clase ejecuta la acción y quiero saber el nombre de la instancia que ejecuta dicha acción agregando una linea desde la superClase. Al final de cuentas no quiero ir poniendo un nuevo set por cada instancia o reescribir el constructor.

Comment: si le he dejado una respuesta en esta pregunta, para un caso mas concreto de llamada a metos ect puede mirar esta pregunta, aqui -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66816/se-puede-obtener-el-nombre-de-una-variable-en-java/ Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apartir de Java 8 usted puede hacer uso de la reflexion.

use:

- `import java.lang.reflect.Field;`
- `.getName()`

---

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public String quesito = new String ("test");
    public String lechita = new String ("test");
    public String lechita = new String ("test");

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException, java.lang.IllegalAccessException
    {

     Ideone t = new Ideone();
     for(Field f : t.getClass().getFields()) {

      System.out.println("nombre instancia: " + f.getName());
     }
  }
}
```

Nota: se usa un `String` porque yo no tengo esa clase, y para no hacer mas largo el ejemplo, se usa la clase `String` pues es la simulacion de las suyas, pero deberia de funcionar igual.

Test:

<kbd>[Ideone](http://ideone.com/fM823N)</kbd>

Comment: Gracias por publicar un respuesta. Es exactamente lo que buscaba. Lo pondré a prueba.

Comment: Lo que devuelves es el nombre de un **atributo de una clase**. No necesitas Java 8 para esto, existe desde hace mucho en Java. Si tú tienes una variable `CualquierTipo x` en un método, no se puede saber el nombre `"x"` en tiempo de ejecución.

Answer (score 6):

La instancia no tiene "nombre".

Lo que tu ves es una *referencia*, que te dirige a lo que es la instancia en sí. Pero el nombre de la referencia es sólo para que puedas usarla para compilar tu programa (en lugar de, por ejemplo, usar el valor del *stackpointer* más un desplazamiento). Por ejemplo, el código compilado no mantiene el nombre de las variables locales, lo desconoce completamente.

Para ilustrarlo, piensa que haces:

```
quesito = lechita;
```

Ahora las dos referencias apuntan a la misma instancia. ¿Cuál es el "nombre" de ésta?

Si quieres identificar una instancia de una clase por un atributo, incluye ese atributo dentro de la clase y dale un valor. Por ejemplo:

```
public class ProductoLacteo { //Nota: en singular, porque cada instancia representa un producto
  private String nombre;
  public ProductoLacte(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
  }
  ...
}

ProductoLacteo lechita = new ProductoLacteo("Lechita");
```

Ahora ya puedes obtener el "nombre" accediendo a la propiedad (mediante un *getter*). También puedes reimplementar `toString`, y quizás `equals` y `hashCode`, en relación con él.

Comment: No se mucho pero me imagino que en algún momento Java necesita el nombre para referenciar a la instancia aunque despues lo deseche. No será posible capturarlo en este momento? Talvez hablo de algo más profundo que un simple get pero me gustaría investigarlo más a fondo.

Comment: El nombre de las variables desaparece, está ahí sólo para que puedas hacer referencia en el momento de compilar. El nombre de los atributos sí que se mantiene, porque pueden ser llamados desde otras clases. Y en ninguno de los casos, el nombre que se usa para identificar una referencia altera en lo más mínimo a la instancia referenciada (repito, ¿qué pasa si haces `quesito = lechita;`?)

Comment: +1 El título de la pregunta muestra que estás confundiendo los objetos (instancias de clases) con las variables. Pero las variables solo _referencian_ a los objetos ( y varias variables pueden referenciar a un solo objeto). Y los nombres de las variables (locales) solo se conocen en tiempo de compilacion, en tiempo de ejecución desaparecieron, por lo que es imposible conocerlas.

Answer (score 0):

El nombre de la variable es solo el identificador del espacio en memoria, la instancia de un objeto no tiene nombre en si, podría tener una propiedad pero no serviría para tu idea a menos que la propiedad almacene el nombre de variable del objeto.