# ¿Se puede obtener el nombre de una variable en Java?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un código de prueba y en el mismo necesito **obtener el nombre de la variable, no el valor de la misma**, pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo.

**NOTA:** **Lo que quiero obtener es el nombre que he dado a la variable, no el nombre de la Clase**, que en el caso del ejemplo sería la Clase String.

Si tengo esto:

```
String sPedro = new String ("Pedro");
String sPablo = new String ("Pedro");
```

quiero saber cómo obtener los valores `sPedro` y `sPablo`, sería como aplicar una especie de método `getName()` algo más o menos así:

```
//Este código no funciona
System.out.println(sPedro.getName());
System.out.println(sPablo.getName());
```

**Resultado**

```
sPedro
sPablo
```

Comment: @M.Gress Me refiero al nombre de la **variable** (sPedro, sPablo), no al nombre de la **Clase**.

Comment: Pero es similiar ya que en la pregunta quiere obtener el nombre de la instancia, no de la clase. Y por eso supongo que tendrias que hacer algo similiar.

Comment: La otra solución no me sirve. A no ser que la respuesta sea **_No. La instancia no tiene nombre_.** ¿esa es la respuesta? ya que, lo que quiero saber es si hay alguna manera de obtener el valor `sPedro` de: `String sPedro = new String ("Pedro");` No lo veo en aquella respuesta. Es para un código de prueba.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si entiendo bien su pregunta, "pero por los comentarios me hace dudar", apartir de Java 8 usted puede hacer uso de la reflexion.

use:

- `import java.lang.reflect.Field;`
- `.getName()`

---

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public String sPedro = new String ("Pedro");
    public String sPablo = new String ("Pedro");

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException, java.lang.IllegalAccessException
    {

     Ideone t = new Ideone();
     for(Field f : t.getClass().getFields()) {

      System.out.println("nombre: " + f.getName());
     }
  }
}
```

Test <kbd>[Ideone](http://ideone.com/DDkhAi)</kbd>

---

> UPDATE: añadido por comentario de lo que quiere hacer exactamente.

Bien segun entidendo su comentario *...Lo que quiero obtener son los valores sPedroy sPablo...* -> `sPedro.getName()` me imagino que `.getName()` es un getter en la clase, en este momento seria confuso usar ese nombre de metodo para el siguiente ejemplo, pues Field cuenta con un nombre similar, para que sea mas tendible he cambiado `.getName()` por `getNombre()` que devuelve el valor de la variable `test` que contiene el nombre que se le asigna desde el contructor en la inicializacion.

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException, java.lang.IllegalAccessException
    {

         Ideone i = new Ideone();
         Init test = i.new Init();

         for(Field f : test.getClass().getFields()) {

            System.out.println("nombre instancia : " + f.getName());

            if (f.getType() == Test.class) {

                Class<?> clazz = Ideone.Test.class;
                Method method = clazz.getMethod("getNombre");
                Ideone.Test typ = (Ideone.Test)f.get(test);

                method.invoke(typ);

                System.out.println("nombre que contiene la variable test : " + typ.getNombre());
            }
         }
      }

      private class Init{

        public Test sPedro = new Test("Pedro");
        public Test sPablo = new Test("Pablo");


      }
      private class Test{

        String test;

        public Test(String nombre){
            test = nombre;
        }
        public String getNombre(){
            return test;
        }
      }
    }
```

Test <kbd>[Ideone](http://ideone.com/56uMdQ)</kbd>

---

stdout:

```
nombre instancia : sPedro
nombre que contiene la variable test : Pedro
nombre instancia : sPablo
nombre que contiene la variable test : Pablo
```

---

en esta linea `Method method = clazz.getMethod("getNombre");` getNombre es el nombre del metodo que vamos a invocar despues, que hace referencia al nombre del getter en la clase.

despues en esta otra linea `method.invoke(typ);` invocamos el metodo pasandole la instancia, en la documentacion que le dejo al final, puede profundizar mas si quiere pasa pasar algumentos ect. `invoke(Object obj,  Object ... args)` seria en el segundo parametro.

---

**NOTA:** Tras volver a leer yo imaginaba e imagino que la clase `String` que usa era para simular una clase mas compleja, pues ahora tengo esa duda, si las variables son `String` y lo que quiere es el valor es mucho mas simple que lo anterior solo tiene que usar lo siguiente:

```
for(Field f : t.getClass().getFields()) {

  System.out.println("nombre: " + (String)f.get(t));

}
```

Si la clase tiene otro tipo de variables que no `String` puede hacer uso de `if (f.getType() == String.class) {`

---

Documentacion quizas le sea util:

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_Reflection/index.htm

Comment: +1 Lo que quiero obtener son los valores `sPedro`y `sPablo`para usarlos en un código de demostración, estuve mirando y creo que Reflection sería la solución, gracias por la respuesta, la probaré en cuanto pueda. Casi todas las respuestas en inglés hablan de Reflection. Aunque si hubiese una forma directa como `sPedro.getName()` sería lo ideal. Gracias,

Comment: Gracias. No sé si me he explicado bien. **Yo quiero obtener el nombre de la variable de la forma más sencilla posible**. Probé el primer ejemplo y se acerca más a lo que quiero. Lo del método `getName` era sólo un ejemplo. La idea es, como quiero usar eso en un código de prueba, poder mostrar el nombre de varias variables con una simple llamada al estilo:  `sPedro.metodoGetNombre()` o `metodoGetNombre(sPedro)`. Creo que el 1er. ejemplo podría valer, creando un método al cual le pase la variable y me devuelva **su nombre**, no su instancia, ni su valor... Creí que esto era más sencillo en Java.

Comment: @A.Cedano de su ultimo comentario -> *...Yo quiero obtener el nombre de la variable de la forma más sencilla posible...* pienso que el primer ejemplo es el mas sencillo. Ahora esta parte -> *Creo que el primer ejemplo podría resolver mi problema, creando un método al cual le pase el objeto y me devuelva el nombre de variable* Pienso que **si el objeto contiene las variables** si, es igual que el primer ejemplo solo que ajustandolo a un metodo, pero lo que pasa hasta donde yo se, no puede hacer el pasarle una `String instancia` a un metodo y que este le diga el nombre de la instancia...

Comment: pues por un lado, los nombre de las variables que se muestran son referente a las que tiene el objeto que se le pasaria, lo que el metodo le ...mostraria serian **el nombre de las variables** que exponga ese objeto el que se le **pasa**. *y por otro lado imagine esto usted tiene una instancia nombre_X, y la pasa a un metodo y el cual tiene como nombre de parametro instancia nombre_Z, como sabria el nombre de la instancia*. Espero explicarme bien.Saludos

Comment: Pues se trata de eso: **saber de la forma más sencilla posible** que cuando yo crée el objeto  : `String sPedro = new String("Pedro")` le di a **esa** variable el nombre de `sPedro`. No importa que el contenido de la variable cambie en cualquier momento, yo quiero conocer el nombre que se le ha dado.

Comment: @A.Cedano yo no se si dice esto -> *No importa que el contenido de la variable cambie en cualquier momento* como ejemplo, creo que si, pues yo no creo que mencionara algo asi, anyway, la forma que creo mas sencilla repito es basada en el primer ejemplo ya sea como en el mismo ejemplo o creando un metodo, sea como fuere, se le mostraran el nombre de las variables que ese objeto "el que se le pasa de ser un metodo" exponga, puede volver a leer la respuesta y mirando los test y jugando con ellos para que los entienda mejor...

Comment: ..., he intente hacer lo que quiere, si tiene algun problema al crear lo que busca puede hacer otra pregunta con en ejemplo mas especifico y donde esta teniendo los errores y como lo esta intento implementar. Saludos

Comment: En efecto, el primer ejemplo era lo que buscaba. Muchas gracias por todo.