# Conocer el nombre de un objeto en java

Tags: java

Hola agradecería que me apoyaran a contestar una pregunta a la que no le he encontrado una respuesta concreta.
La cuestión es que deseo saber que nombre recibe un objeto al cual yo no le he asignado un nombre como por ejemplo:  JPPanel01.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
Mis preguntas son: ¿Cuál es el nombre que recibe el FlowLayout que creamos en el pase de parámetros? y ¿Como puedo usar ese componente otra vez?

Comment: Creo que te interesa esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/65694/14311

Comment: Ver también [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/66816/29967). Aunque en tu caso, dado que el objeto es pasado directamente al método sin crearlo previamente, la única forma de intentar algo sería sobre-escribiendo el método `setLayout` y trabajar allí el parámetro (sería algo que tendría poco sentido desde un punto de vista práctico y realista), más fácil sería crear primero la nueva instancia del objeto antes de pasarla al método y usar `Reflection` para encontrar el nombre del objeto.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que no tienes una referencia a ese objeto. Para ello debes proceder de la 
siguiente manera:

```
FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
JPPanel01.setLayout(layout);
```

Comment: ¿Pero el compilador de java como lo diferencia de los demás?

Comment: No tiene porque hacerlo porque no lo utiliza más, ese objeto creado solo es utilizado por el método, esto existe en otros lenguajes orientados a objetos.

Comment: Para ser más claro, en tu ejemplo, el operador **new** crea un objeto de tipo **FlowLayout** y se lo pasa al método **setLayout()**, este objeto solo existe para esa llamada al método.

Comment: Gracias creo que ya me ha quedado claro

Answer (score -1):

A rasgos generales @LázaroMER tiene razón pero en realidad es algo más complejo.

Variables de instancia y objetos se crean en la parte de memoria que en java se conoce como *heap*. Variables locales en el *stack*. Cuando creas un objeto este vive en el *heap* pero al asignarlo a una variable en realidad pasas una referencia. Básicamente el compilador verá un puntero de memoria. En el caso que te interesa el método que recibe la referencia de objeto a nivel bajo va a recibir un puntero (y más todavía - este puntero se mete en el stack del procesador para pasarlo al método) que luego puede usar (no deja de ser una referencia al objeto).
Si te es más fácil puedes pensar que el compilador o la máquina virtual tienen sus propias variables donde se guardan las referencias a los objetos creados. Simplemente piensa que un objeto es una dirección de memoria. ¿Qué necesita un método para poder usar un objeto? Esta misma dirección. Y esto es lo que va a recibir aunque tu no puedas seguir usando el objeto fuera del método.

No sé si esto aclara algo más tus dudas.

Comment: A quién no le ha gustado y vota en negativo? Al menos que diga **qué** no le gusta.